# s3 redirect via cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I want to use S3 redirect via CloudFront.

Bucket policy

```
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity ######"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        },
```

[image]

The s3 redirect URL works. But the CloudFront domain does not work. The CloudFront origin is the correct bucket. What is the problem? By the way, the bucket is empty.

```
<ListBucketResult>
<Name>bucket name</Name>
<Prefix/>
<Marker/>
<MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys>
<IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated>
</ListBucketResult>
```

I have also tried redirection rules

```
[
    {
        "Redirect": {
            "HostName": "my.app",
            "HttpRedirectCode": "301",
            "Protocol": "https"
        }
    }
]
```

I get the same result.

Comment: I think I solved it. The CloudFront origin should be the redirect S3 URL.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the s3 redirect URL.